# Daily count of individuals detected by each monitoring station

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have a ver large (2+ years) data set of acoustic telemetry data. The study is based on constantly monitoring several animals fitted with an acoustic tag, using stations throughout the study area to detect them.
I want to obtain a summary table that shows the number of individual tags detected by each station per day (e.g.,"on 2019-04-02, five tags were detected at station 1, three tags at station 2"). Other time frames interest me too but a daily count is the most relevant right now.

I haven't worked with R for long, so I'm having a hard time coming up with this kind of code. I don't really have anything useful to show. I have several individuas and stations, but below is an example of how the data looks like (already dropped time of day).

Thanks,

```
Date.and.time  Station      Transmitter

2019-04-02     Station_3    Tag_1
2019-04-02     Station_26   Tag_3
2019-04-02     Station_3    Tag_13
2019-04-02     Station_15   Tag_15
.
.
.
2021-10-14     Station_13   Tag_20
2021-10-15     Station_8    Tag_8
2021-10-15     Station_23   Tag_31
```

Comment: something like: `df = df %>% group_by(Date.and.time, Station) %>% summarise(COUNT = n_distinct(Transmitter))` might do the trick.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.